# What is this flowering tree/shrub with red flowers?

Tags: identification

Does anyone know what the name of this plant is? It was about 6 feet tall but I thought it died so I cut it down and it has since regrown out of the stump that was left. It has very wide leaves on it.  I’m located in Jacksonville Florida. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's Clerodendrum paniculatum, common name Pagoda flower, a fast growing, deciduous shrub in colder zones, but which may retain its leaves in warmer regions. Average height is 3-5 feet and it prefers a rich, moisture retentive soil - flowers are produced from summer to autumn. Perhaps it
didn't get sufficient water at some point, and died back temporarily, causing you to think it had actually died. Clearly, it has not! https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Clerodendrum_paniculatum.htm

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been searching for so long to find its identity. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Good one, Bamboo!